# Getting Custom Object Tab ID Edit page

Tags: soql, tab

I'm designing a custom Visualforce page and I am trying to create a link that when clicked, will take the user to the custom object tab's edit page. I have included pictures below to show what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know how to get that ID either through a SOQL query or any other method?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

- Ryan

Comment: My first question is - why do you want to do this? There may be a better way to achieve what you want than directing people to the setup page (which will require the "Customise Application" permission)

Comment: I am creating a custom version of the Quick Access Menu. In the quick access menu, there is a link called "Edit Tab" that directs the user to the object's custom object tab's edit page.

So I'm building the URL that will allow a user to navigate directly to the edit tab page just like the standard quick access menu provided by Salesforce. 

@AlexTennant do you happen to know how to get the ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get at this through Apex in a supported way, as the tab information is part of the metadata API:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_tab.htm

and the metadata API isn't available in Apex.

However, Financial Force have created an Apex wrapper for the metadata API, so you may find that gives you what you are looking for :

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi